# problem with SelectLayerByAttribute management in script

Tags: python, arcpy, select-by-attribute

My problem is that this tool works perfectly in IDLE or PyScripter programs, but if I use in the script in ArcGIS desktop this problem occurs: `arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:ERROR 000582...`

Why does it not execute in ArcGIS script but works in the programs?

The tool `SelectLayerByAttribute management` is inside the `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`

This is my code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

territory= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
path= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
territory_lyr=  path+ "territorios_lyr"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(territory,territory_lyr)
fields= ("FID", "avg_mindis", "I_conc", "Max_lenght","TamanoTerr")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(territory,  fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        currentID= row[0]
        where= "FID="+str(currentID)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(territory_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION",where)
```

[image: Image ArcToolbox scrpit of Arcgis Desktop and I am print the error in the line select by atribute]

Comment: Try to use some simple `print` statements to see if you can identify which step is causing the error. I'd start by printing the `territory_lyr` variable to make sure the path is what you are expecting.

Comment: thanks 
but I have already done, the route and variables are fine. 
because the code works in other programs

Comment: Are you running this as a custom python tool or copy paste in the python editor? It won't work for the latter since your variables (as currently defined) have to come from a tool.

Comment: Thanks Pual, but i use the code python in a script of ArcToolbox, so, my variables using this scrpit coming from the user in this case i get out the error. in the other case, if i use the python editor o PyScripter program this code worked successful

Answer (score 1):

At this point, the problem with your where clause is that it will be interpreted as (assuming  FID = 1 
what you should have is "FID" = 1 (or [FID] with personnal geodatabase), therefore the python command need to be

```
' "FID" = ' + str(row[0])
```

Remark : It is a bit strange to create a layer inside a cursor, especially with FID's which are ranked suites of integers and relying on the same feature class, but you probably have good reasons in the remaining of your code. Maybe if you give more details about the rest of your code (in another question), a better solution could be provided. For instance you could immediately work with the geometry from your cursor, or create your layer in a loop like this :

```
for i in range(int(arcpy.GetCount_management(territory_lyr).getOutput(0)) ):
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(territory_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION",'"FID" =' + str(i) ) #maybe i + 1 depending of your input type
```